# font detection through javascript only( no flash)

Tags: javascript

here is the code for detecting installed fonts available to a browser though javascript,css method.(no flash). this code is modified from lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect.

```
 var Detector =
     {
       init: function()
    {
    this.h = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    this.d = document.createElement("DIV");
    this.s = document.createElement("SPAN");
    this.d.appendChild(this.s);
    this.d.style.fontFamily = "sans";
    this.s.style.fontFamily = "sans";
    this.s.style.fontSize = "72px";
    this.s.innerHTML = "mmmmmmmmmmlil";
    this.h.appendChild(this.d);
    this.defaultWidth = this.s.offsetWidth;
    this.defaultHeight = this.s.offsetHeight;
    this.h.removeChild(this.d)
   },
   test: function(a)
   {
    this.h.appendChild(this.d);
    var b = [];
    b.name = this.s.style.fontFamily = a;
    b.width = this.s.offsetWidth;
    b.height = this.s.offsetHeight;
    this.h.removeChild(this.d);
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    if (a == "serif") {
        b.found = true
    } else {
        b.found = (b.width != this.defaultWidth || b.height != this.defaultHeight)
    }
    return b
   },

   getFontList: function()
   {
    this.init();
    var a = ["cursive", "monospace", "serif", "sans-serif", "fantasy", "default",      "Arial", "Arial Black", "Arial Narrow", "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Book Antiqua", "Bookman Old Style", "Bradley Hand ITC", "Bodoni MT", "Calibri", "Century", "Century Gothic", "Casual", "Comic Sans MS", "Consolas", "Copperplate Gothic Bold", "Courier", "Courier New", "English Text MT", "Felix Titling", "Futura", "Garamond", "Geneva", "Georgia", "Gentium", "Haettenschweiler", "Helvetica", "Impact", "Jokerman", "King", "Kootenay", "Latha", "Liberation Serif", "Lucida Console", "Lalit", "Lucida Grande", "Magneto", "Mistral", "Modena", "Monotype Corsiva", "MV Boli", "OCR A Extended", "Onyx", "Palatino Linotype", "Papyrus", "Parchment", "Pericles", "Playbill", "Segoe Print", "Shruti", "Tahoma", "TeX", "Times", "Times New Roman", "Trebuchet MS", "Verdana", "Verona"];
    var c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        var b = this.test(a[i]);
        if (b.found) {
            c += b.name + ","
        }
    }
    return c.slice(0, - 1)
}
  };
```

Please help me how to document.write() to Display Fonts list. i just want to print those font list text in the browser.

Comment: `document.write(Detector.getFontList())`

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes.i tried that.But it is not working. Please test it.

Comment: I have done. It works.

Comment: @OrangeDog but i am getting blank page. can you send me screenshot?

Comment: You cannot document.write after the page loaded. It will wipe the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/TwDdt/)

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=Detector.getFontList();
}
</script>
```

Result on my box:

> cursive,monospace,serif,sans-serif,fantasy,default,Arial,Arial Black,Arial Narrow,Book Antiqua,Bookman Old Style,Calibri,Century,Century Gothic,Comic Sans MS,Consolas,Courier,Courier New,Garamond,Georgia,Helvetica,Impact,Jokerman,Latha,Lucida Console,Magneto,Mistral,Monotype Corsiva,Onyx,Palatino Linotype,Parchment,Playbill,Shruti,Tahoma,Trebuchet MS,Verdana